# Proper use of boost::shared_ptr in a list

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a question related to `boost::shared_ptr<>` in C++. I am currently willing to perform a smart deletion of the items of my list:

- If the item is in use, don't do anything, and delete it later
- If the item is not in use, delete it

This is a behavior required by my program.

I am really wondering how to do that properly since the `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<object> >` remove/erase functions causes the deletion of the `shared_ptr<>` and therefore of the real object.

So I finally came up with this solution: use a `std::list<object*>` and inherit `object` from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<>`. That way, when someone needs to use an item from the list, I give them `object->shared_from_this()`.

My questions are the following:

- Would this respect the desired behavior ?
- Does the `boost::shared_ptr<>` associated to `shared_from_this()` takes into consideration the reference to the object in the list ?

I hope my question is explicit enough and that someone will be able to help me. The proper use of the smart pointers in lists is something I'd like to be able to use.

Thank you

Comment: `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<object> >` remove/erase functions cause deletion of the real object *only if that was the last shared_ptr referencing the object*. Which is exactly what you say you want. I'm guessing that you are using shared_ptr and normal pointers to the same object. The answer is simple, don't do that, shared_ptrs only and it will work as you say you want it to. Sometimes I wonder at the ability of newbies to make life difficult for themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, what you said is what I thought. I was getting double frees in my program (that is quite big) and with `valgrind` assumed I was doing it wrong. I tried to reproduce it in a small program and couldn't. I guess I'm a newbie like you said. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you delete a `shared_ptr` you don't delete the real object unless it is not used anywhere else. That's the whole point about using `shared_ptr`.

For instance, if you take one element of the list, copy it and give it to another function, then delete the element from the list, the real object won't be deleted because it is still referenced somewhere else.

Comment: I got the right behavior in a small program I just made. Exactly what you explained. Thank you